# JavaScript append and prepend not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, web-applications

I'm trying to append and prepend an HTML block inside a text-area using a button click, but it's not working in Internet Explorer.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        "use strict";
       $('#export-file').click(function () {          
          document.getElementById("codeToSave").prepend('<!doctype html>\n<html> \n<head>');
          document.getElementById("codeToSave").append($.trim('</body>\n</html>'));
       });
    });


<ul class="control-list">
      <li class="controls" id="export-file" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Export " ><i class="fas fa-download"></i></li>                    
</ul>

<textarea id="codeToSave" disabled class="scrollStyle-3" ></textarea>
```

Comment: Why are you not closing your tags?

Comment: Prepend expects nodes, not a string. That might be part of your problem. Also, what is it you are trying to do? i suspect you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple issues.  First, the when you use the native selectors, they do not return a jQuery object.  So if you want to use the jQuery methods, you have to either put those elements you found inside `$()` or just use the jQuery selector methods.

Secondly, appending the html to the textarea is not displaying it because it is trying to interpret the text before it appends it to the element, even though it is a textarea.  To fix this issue, you can force jQuery to append/prepend data by giving it a TextNode.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";
  $('#export-file').click(function() {
    var $codeToSave = $("#codeToSave");
    
    $codeToSave
        .prepend(document.createTextNode('<!doctype html>\n<html> \n<head>'))
        .append(document.createTextNode($.trim('</body>\n</html>')));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="control-list">
  <li class="controls" id="export-file" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Export "><i class="fas fa-download"></i>Thing</li>
</ul>

<textarea id="codeToSave" disabled class="scrollStyle-3"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually `.prepend` and `.append` are both experimental technologies:

> The [`ParentNode.prepend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend) (respectively [`ParentNode.append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append)) method inserts a set of `Node`  objects or `DOMString` objects before the first child (respectively after the last child) of the `ParentNode`.

But I pretty sure you were looking at using jQuery's [`.prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) and [`.append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) methods. The problem is `document.getElementById("codeToSave")` is an object of type [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) it's not a jQuery object! Thefore you can't apply `.append` nor `.prepend` on it. (expect if you wanted to use the built-in experimental methods, but I'm not sure you are.

If you want to add HTML as text (not as an actual element) inside the text area you can simply change its `textContent` property:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";
  $('#export-file').click(function() {
    
    document.getElementById("codeToSave").textContent = `
      <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">Hello World</div>
      </div>
    `;
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="control-list">
  <li class="controls" id="export-file" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Export "><i class="fas fa-download"></i></li>
</ul>

<textarea id="codeToSave" disabled class="scrollStyle-3"></textarea>
```

Or with jQuery use the method [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";
  $('#export-file').click(function() {
    
    $("#codeToSave").val(`
      <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">Hello World</div>
      </div>
    `.trim());
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="control-list">
  <li class="controls" id="export-file" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Export ">Click Here<i class="fas fa-download"></i></li>
</ul>

<textarea id="codeToSave" disabled class="scrollStyle-3"></textarea>
```